# Performing Division on TFHE (The Fully Fast Homomorphic Encryption)

Tags: c++, division

I'm currently working on a project that involves using the TFHE library, and am currently working on coding the 4 main arithmetic operations. Addition, Subtraction and Multiplication were quite smooth as they were tons of references online, However i am currently stuck on divison with no idea how to proceed. Any advice?

Comment: This is not an advice site. This site is for specific programming related questions. Your experiences here will be vastly improved if you spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask], to learn how the site works and the expectations we have before you begin posting here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a binary division circuit (it has approx the same number of gates as the multiplication circuit).

essentially:

   `q: is the quotient (assumed at most n bits)
   r: temp variable that will end-up containing the remainder
   x: number to divide (assumed m >= n bits)`

idea of the algo:

`r := x  //initialize r with x
for j = m-n downto 0
    use a subtraction circuit to compute: r - 2^j. q
    // s is the result, c the carry (c=1 if the result if < 0)
    r := mux(c,r,s)
    q_i := not(c)`

Of course, from a binary point of view, 2^j.q is just a shift, so it does not involves gates.
Also, all subtractions need only n bits of precision, since the last j bits of 2^j.q are zeros!

This should give you a simple way of implementing the division circuit in TFHE!

Have fun.

Comment: What does q_i refer to? Is it safe to assume that m refers to the size of x, and that the result of the multiplexer is r?